# Creating an Python/py2app application that simply opens a terminal on launch?

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I've written a nice Python application that is basically an HTTP proxy for SMS modems, and I'd like to make it a double-clickable application on Macs. So far I've been including a .commmand file which is double-clickable, which basically consists of

```
cd `dirname $0`
(sleep 8;open http://127.0.0.1:8080/)&
mac/slingshotsms.app/Contents/MacOS/slingshotsms
```

How can I make the main .app executable call a different place / or what's the easiest way to make an application that is basically a wrapper for a terminal utility and only displays its output? Currently double-clicking on the application will use the open utility on Macs - I want to emulate the behavior of double-clicking on Contents/MacOS/slingshotsms when double-clicking on the application icon. any tips?

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for 'easy', try just giving your python script a `.command` suffix, and make sure it's executable.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# file: hello.command

print 'hello world'
```

If you're looking for 'polished', then you probably want to learn about Launch Services, PyObjC, Interface Builder, NIB files, app wrappers, and all sorts of Mac OS X-specific technology details. But, note that PyObjC is nearly impossible to use for anything non-trivial without already knowing, more or less, how to do the same task using the Objective-C Cocoa APIs. PyObjC is a fairly thin wrapper around those APIs, and you have to know the Cocoa idioms / design patterns to understand how the moving parts fit together.

Comment: Hey,

I'm using py2app and the setuptools system so that I can have all of the dependencies of this app packaged and a Python environment included... so having a .command file doesn't really jive here.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need a terminal, but instead just want an app wrapper around a script, have a look at [Platypus](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/platypus)

Answer (score 0):

Write an AppleScript application that launches Terminal and runs your Python script (which will be inside the application's bundle).